# some form fields are cleared on bindAndValidate() after formbackingobject() populate them correctly, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I m working on some existing code where the controller overrides the formbackingobject method.

the object returned from the formbackingobject is populated correctly, but when it reaches the jsp some fields are being blank. I did some debugging and I found that some of the fields data is cleared in the BaseCommandController class, in the bindAndValidate method, and specifically in the line binder.bind(request); i m not able to find any validator where this data would be changed.

Any idea how those fields get cleared and why it that method.

Answer (score 0):

The validators shouldn't be the ones changed your object. Your object would have values associate with the values in the request parameters after binding step.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can you collaborate more on "your object would have values associate with the values in the request parameters after binding step."

Comment: I think you just put a condition break-point at the fields which will be cleaned and see what happen to it ;-) .

Comment: that is what I did. I have the variable view opened, and the field has the value,  but then right after the binder.bind(request) I can clearly the see the field value being cleared.

Comment: You put the break-point at the setter of the field, but couldn't know why was it cleaned?

Comment: in the setter, I can clearly see the set parameter being empty the second time. so my question is where would the data change between binder.bind(request); and rendering the jsp

Comment: You must know where/when the data change by following the stacktrace from the bugger when it stops at the second call to the setter. If there is no thing special in the code, the attribute is probably reset because of a request parameter like paramField1=&...